# SQL Syntax error - can't find the error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE 'categories'(
    'id' SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'category' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'),
    UNIQUE KEY 'category' ('category') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE 'orders' ( 
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'user_id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    'transaction_id' VARCHAR(19) NOT NULL, 
    'payment_status' VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL, 
    'payment_amount' DECIMAL(6,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    'payment_date_time' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'), 
    KEY 'user_id' ('user_id') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE 'pages' ( 
    'id' MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'category_id' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    'title' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    'description' TINYTEXT NOT NULL, 
    'content' LONGTEXT NOT NULL, 
    'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'), 
    KEY 'category_id' ('category_id'), 
    KEY 'creation_date' ('date_created') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE 'pdfs' ( 
    'id' SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'tmp_name' CHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    'title' VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
    'description' TINYTEXT NOT NULL, 
    'file_name' VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL, 
    'size' MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
    'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'), 
    UNIQUE KEY 'tmp_name' ('tmp_name'), 
    KEY 'date_created' ('date_created') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 

CREATE TABLE 'users' ( 
    'id' INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    'type' ENUM ('member','admin') NOT NULL, 
    'username' VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
    'email' VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL, 
    'pass' VARBINARY(32) NOT NULL, 
    'first_name' VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
    'last_name' VARCHAR (40) NOT NULL, 
    'date_expires' DATE NOT NULL, 
    'date_created' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
    'date_modified' TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00', 
    PRIMARY KEY ('id'), 
    UNIQUE KEY 'username' ('username'), 
    UNIQUE KEY 'email' ('email') 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

.............................................................................

I cannot find the SQL error here.

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''categories' ('id' SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 'category' VARCHAR(30) NOT' at line 1

Please help. I am using MySQL 4.4.x on a shared server.

Comment: not sure if this is the problem but you don't need single quotes around the table name.  could be what's throwing it off.     I would start by just creating one table at a time and see if it is something downline that could be crashing it also

Answer (score 7):

You're surrounding your table and column names with `'`, it should be ` (backtick)

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` 
(`id` SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
 `category` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, 
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `category` (`category`) 
 ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of your single quotes or as @Joachim Isaksson said, use backticks `.

```
CREATE TABLE categories (id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,   category VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (id),  UNIQUE KEY(category)   ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Also next time, simplify your problem. You have a problem with the first `CREATE TABLE` statement. There is no need to print everything else. Also some formatting would be nice too :-).

Comment: Thank-you for helping. The problem is now solved. I have just started to learn MySQL/ PHP, & am finding it an uphill battle at the moment. cc:  @Joachim Isaksson