# SQL syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE  `users` (

 `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
 `type` ENUM(  `member` ,  `admin` ) NOT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR( 30 ) NOT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 80 ) NOT NULL ,
 `pass` VARBINARY( 32 ) NOT NULL , 
 `first_name` VARCHAR( 20 ) NOT NULL , 
 `last_name` VARCHAR( 40 ) NOT NULL , 
 `date_expires` DATE NOT NULL , 
 `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT `0000-00-00 00:00:00` ,
PRIMARY KEY (  `id` ) , 
UNIQUE KEY  `username` (  `username` ) ,
UNIQUE KEY  `email` (  `email` ) 
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

MySQL said:

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`member`,`admin`) NOT NULL, `username` VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
>   `email` VARCHAR(80)' at line 3

The shared server I am using, uses 4.4. Thanks for reading. I am an absolute novice, having only been learning php/mysql for one month, so please speak in layman's terms.

Comment: Don't use markup (eg `<br/>`) when posting. Instead use the code section toggle in the edit toolbar.

Comment: Looks like you overcompensated for the last issue.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: that's SO's formatting getting confused by # character

Comment: @Mchl - I meant that his [last syntax error](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9467804/697449) was using single-quote for table/column names, and it looks like he switched to back-ticks for everything, including enums.

Answer (score 5):

You need to quote ENUM values

```
type ENUM( 'member' , 'admin' ) NOT NULL ,
```

not backtick them as you do now

Same thing for this line

```
`date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT `0000-00-00 00:00:00`
```

should be

```
`date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Thank-you @Anthony Grist & @Mchl . This may be an incredibly stupid question, but why do you use ' rather than ` here?

Comment: Because backticks ` are for denoting database objects like tables and columns, while ' is for delimiting string values.

Comment: @Matthew: Please read the manual; _all_ of this information is there (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html & http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

[**This**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html) page indicates that your ENUM values should be strings, so need to be surrounded by single quotes.

```
type ENUM( 'member' , 'admin' ) NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

okey fixed it here is it :)

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
type ENUM( 'member' , 'admin' ) NOT NULL ,
`username` varchar(30) NOT NULL default '',
`password` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
`first_name` varchar (15) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar (30) NOT NULL,
`gender` ENUM('male',  'female') NOT NULL default 'male',
`email` varchar(50) NOT NULL default '',
`skype` varchar(50) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
`facebook` varchar(150) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
`location` varchar(100) NOT NULL default 'Not Specified',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY (`email`),
KEY (`email`, `password`)
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```